# SQL Sort table and Update Column

Tags: sql, excel, ms-access

Hi can anyone tell me the how I can do the following with SQL In an MS Access Database.?

I have a table that looks like this:

MyTable

```
Plan    Item        Sort_Number
-------------------------------------
11026    ZSC1753D   
11018    PS13-2     
11026    ZSC1753B   
11018    PSHH278B   
11026    ZSO1753A   
11018    PS3169     
11027    ZSC1754B   
11027    ZSC1754A   
11026    ZSC1753A   
11026    ZSC1753C
```

I have a table (above) which needs to be sorted first by the Plan (Column 1), then by Ascending order of Item (Column 2) and the third column Sort Number needs to be populated with sequential numbers of 1 to xx.. for each of the different plans.

So the final sorted table will look like this:

MyTable

```
Plan    Item    Sort_Number
-------------------------------------
11018   PS13-2      1
11018   PS3169      2
11018   PSHH278B    3
11026   ZSC1753A    1
11026   ZSC1753B    2
11026   ZSC1753C    3
11026   ZSC1753D    4
11026   ZSO1753A    5
11027   ZSC1754A    1
11027   ZSC1754B    2
```

Can I do this with SQL? In an MS Access Database.

Thanks  in Advance

Comment: Wich RDBMS are you using? SQL Server? Oracle? MySQL?

Comment: You can do it with VBA. Just iterate over the recordset.

Comment: I ask my self, how the OP comment appeared after @Remou comment, some minutes ago only my comment and his where visible

Comment: @user1180536: Follow what Remou has to say and update things using recordset and looping over it.

Answer (score 3):

```
UPDATE myTable d, 
    (SELECT Plan, Item, 
       (SELECT count(*) + 1 
        FROM myTable i 
        WHERE i.Plan = o.Plan and i.Item < o.Item) as Sort_Number
    FROM myTable o) as s
SET d.Sort_Number = s.Sort_Number
WHERE d.Plan = s.Plan and d.Item = s.Item
```

OR

```
UPDATE myTable d INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT Plan, Item, 
       (SELECT count(*) + 1 
        FROM myTable i 
        WHERE i.Plan = o.Plan and i.Item < o.Item) as Sort_Number
    FROM myTable o) s
ON d.Plan = s.Plan and d.Item = s.Item
SET d.Sort_Number = s.Sort_Number
```

**EDIT**: I know that this isn't efficient but it will work without any problem for limited number of records.

**EDIT2**: Please note that I haven't tried this query in MS-Access. I hope it gives you input on how it can be done.

**EDIT3**: Using a temporary table

```
SELECT Plan, Item, 
       (SELECT count(*) + 1 
        FROM myTable i 
        WHERE i.Plan = o.Plan and i.Item < o.Item) as Sort_Number
INTO TEMPTABLEFORTEST
FROM myTable o

UPDATE myTable i 
INNER JOIN TEMPTABLEFORTEST o 
ON i.Plan = o.Plan and i.Item = o.Item set i.Sort_Number = o.Sort_Number

DROP Table TEMPTABLEFORTEST
```

Comment: "the third column Sort Number needs to be populated " -- this is not going to happen with that query.

Comment: @Remou: Yes, I am sorry I didn't see the part where OP asked for the need to update the table. I will try & update the answer.

Comment: "Operation must use an updatable query" :)

Comment: @Remou: I don't have MS-Access on my machine to try this out. Do you know of a tool such as SQL-Fiddle for Access? :(

Comment: I do not believe you can do this with SQL in MS Access unless you use a user defined function, and therefore I believe it would be best done in VBA, hence my comment on the OP.

Comment: @Remou: Updated the answer using a temporary table in the middle.

Comment: This is a really bad idea in MS Access and should only be done when there is no alternative because it leads to massive bloat. There is an alternative and that is to use VBA.

Comment: @Remou: Yes, it is a bad idea. However, I tried hard to make sure I could do it in Access using visdata and a copy of NWind.mdb lying on my machine. :)

Answer (score 1):

Creating a SQL statement to *update* `Sort_Number` is challenging.  However, a VBA procedure for this is fairly simple.  I tested this one in Access 2007 with your sample data in a table named "*Plans*".  Substitute your real table name in the "FROM" line below.

```
Public Sub Update_Sort_Numbers()
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Dim strSelect As String
    Dim lngCurrentPlan As Long
    Dim lngSortNum As Long

    strSelect = "SELECT p.Plan, p.Item, p.Sort_Number" & vbCrLf & _
        "FROM Plans AS p" & vbCrLf & _
        "ORDER BY p.Plan, p.Item;"
    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strSelect)
    With rs
        Do While Not .EOF
            If rs!Plan <> lngCurrentPlan Then
                lngCurrentPlan = rs!Plan
                lngSortNum = 1
            End If
            Debug.Print !Plan, ![Item], lngSortNum
            .Edit
            !Sort_Number = lngSortNum
            .Update
            lngSortNum = lngSortNum + 1
            .MoveNext
        Loop
        .Close
    End With
    Set rs = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing
End Sub
```